# Unknown property with class variable PHP in Yii encountered in unit testing

Tags: php, yii

In a data access object using SQL for prepared statements, I have several strings with the SQL and binding variables initialized.  One such is

```
private $insertQuestionSql = "
INSERT IGNORE INTO bgt.question_models (nodeId, questionId, parentId, state, version,
questionText, userResponseText) 
VALUES (NID, QID, PID, ST, V, QT, URT)";
```

This statement is declared and used in the same class as the DAO function

```
public function createQuestion(QuestionTemplateModel $qt) {
  //create database connection and initialize transaction
  $connection = Yii::app()->db;
  $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

  try {
    $command = $connection->createCommand($this->insertQuestionSql);
```

In Yii, `$connection` is an instance of `CDbConnection` and returns an instance of `CDbCommand` via the `createCommand` function.

Since I'm accessing this property within the class, I should be able to access the string variable.  Why is that not happening here?

The full error is

```
"Unknown property 'insertQuestionSql' for class 'QuestionDAOTest'."
```

This behavior happens regardless of

- Changing SQL string
- Removing first newline character

In addition, removing the `$this->` results in an `undefined variable: insertQuestionSql` error.  This occurs despite changing the access modifier to both `public` and `protected`

Comment: What's the full error message, is it `Unknown` or `Undefined`, is it a notice, warning, fatal error or exception?

Comment: It would appear that this has been solved before by removing new lines from the property definition. Try removing the new lines http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12043-chapter-5-page-90-using-fixtures/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the exceptions are still shown.  I've also opened a question at the yiiframework forums.

Comment: I think they will have more ideas as it looks like a yii specific problem to me. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be helpful to anyone, but I figured out a solution.

First, the `CDbCommand::bindParam` follows the standard PHP [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) syntax in which the placeholders on which variables are to be bound must have the prefix `:`.  Without that prefix, the variables were not being bound to the SQL statement.

Second, for some reason, `private $insertQuestionSql` was always found to be an unknown property when accessing within the class, despite usage of `$this->` prefix when calling the variable.  I worked around this by converting the property to `static` and calling via

```
$command = $connection->createConnection(QuestionDAO::$insertQuestionSql);
```